# Web API - Catch 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: webapi, http-status-code-405

As of now, the Web API application returns the below response body for 405 - Method Not Allowed error. I am trying to change the response body, but I don't know how the delegating handler, `ApiControllerActionSelector` or filter can be used. Can anyone help me on catching the 405 error in server side?

```json
{
message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

Note: My API controllers has `[RoutePrefix]` value.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [DelegatingHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) to catch the outgoing response and override its behaviour like this.

```
public class MethodNotAllowedDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
        {
            // adjust your response here as needed...
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

In Global.asax...

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MethodNotAllowedDelegatingHandler());
```